# Python: Count how often a value occurs with same id

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I try to add a column in panda data frame to count how often a not-null value occurs with same id.

For example, if I have:
[Original Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sAfuy.png)

Then I try to add a third column as below:
[Want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1IC5.png)

Could anyone help me on this? Thanks a lots!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `pandas.groupby` with `.transform('count')`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'ID': [1, 2, 2, 3, 3],
        'Value': [10, 5, None, None, None]
    })


df['Count'] = df.groupby('ID')['Value'].transform('count')
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   ID  Value  Count
0   1   10.0      1
1   2    5.0      1
2   2    NaN      1
3   3    NaN      0
4   3    NaN      0
```